# Poker game winning conditions only executing first if statement

Tags: c++

I am making a basic poker game with my own type of winning conditions but my if statements for the function keeps only outputting the first condition even if the condition hasn't been met. Also sorry about the mess of a function, but I have tried everything and nothing works so tidiness is the last thing on my mind.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

/*  Functions
                */

//Create Deck, Shuffle and print shuffled deck Function
void shuffle(string suits[4], string ranks[13], int deck[52])
{
    //Initialise seed with starting value for random generator
    srand(time(0));

    //Loop to create new unique deck
    for(int i=0;i<52;i++)
    {
        deck[i] = i;
    }

    //This loop will swap each index i with a random index
    for(int j=0;j<52;j++)
    {
        int k = rand() % 52; //Initialse and declare variable equals to random number generator
        int temp = deck[j]; //Initialise a temporary variable to be replaced by random index

        deck[j] = deck[k];
        deck[k] = temp;
    }

    //Determines what suits go with what ranks in the 52 shuffled deck
    cout << "Shuffling cards in deck..." << endl;
    for(int q=0;q<52;q++)
    {
        int s = deck[q]/13; //Determines suit by dividing number by 13 as there is 13 cards in each suit
        int r = deck[q]%13; //Type of card is determined with number by modulus 13
        //cout << ranks[r] << " " << suits[s] << endl; /*This displays the whole shuffled deck*/
    }
}


//Function for drawing 5 cards from shuffled deck for player and computer
void draw(string userName, int deck[52], string suits[4], string ranks[13])
{
    //Initialise array variables for player and computer
    //Players cards
    int suit1[5];
    int rank1[5];

    //Computers Cards
    int suit2[5];
    int rank2[5];

    cout << userName << "'s Cards" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------" << endl;

    //Loops for drawing players 5 cards from shuffled cards in deck
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        suit1[i] = deck[i] / 13;
        rank1[i] = deck[i] % 13;
    }

    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        cout << ranks[rank1[j]] << " " << suits[suit1[j]] << endl;
    }

    cout << "-------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Computer's Cards" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------" << endl;
    //Loops for drawing computers 5 cards from shuffled cards in deck
    for(int k=5;k<10;k++)
    {
        suit2[k] = deck[k] / 13;
        rank2[k] = deck[k] % 13;
    }

    for(int z=5;z<10;z++)
    {
        cout << ranks[rank2[z]] << " " << suits[suit2[z]] << endl;
    }
    cout << "-------------------------------" << endl;
}

int winner(string userName, int rank1[5], int rank2[5], int score1, int score2, string ranks[13], int deck[52])
{
    for(int k=0;k<5;k++)
    {
        if((ranks[rank1[k]].compare(ranks[0])))
        {
            cout << userName << " got 2 points for having rank 2 in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 2;
            return score1;
        }
        if((ranks[rank1[k]].compare(ranks[1])))
        {
            cout << userName << " got 3 points for having rank 3 in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 3;
            return score1;
        }
        if((ranks[rank1[k]].compare(ranks[2])))
        {
            cout << userName << " got 4 points for having rank 4 in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 4;
            return score1;
        }
        if((ranks[rank1[k]].compare(ranks[3])))
        {
            cout << userName << " got 5 points for having rank 5 in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 5;
            return score1;
        }
        if((ranks[rank1[k]].compare(ranks[4])))
        {
            cout << userName << " got 6 points for having rank 6 in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 6;
            return score1;
        }
        if((ranks[rank1[k]].compare(ranks[5])))
        {
            cout << userName << " got 7 points for having rank 7 in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 7;
            return score1;
        }
        if((ranks[rank1[k]].compare(ranks[6])))
        {
            cout << userName << " got 8 points for having rank 8 in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 8;
            return score1;
        }
        if((ranks[rank1[k]].compare(ranks[7])))
        {
            cout << userName << " got 9 points for having rank 9 in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 9;
            return score1;
        }
        if((ranks[rank1[k]].compare(ranks[8])))
        {
            cout << userName << " got 10 points for having rank 10 in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 10;
            return score1;
        }
        if((ranks[rank1[k]].compare(ranks[9])))
        {
            cout << userName << " got 11 points for having a Jack in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 11;
            return score1;
        }
        if((ranks[rank1[k]].compare(ranks[10])))
        {
            cout << userName << " got 12 points for having an Ace in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 12;
            return score1;
        }
        if((ranks[rank1[k]].compare(ranks[11])))
        {
            cout << userName << " got 13 points for having a King in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 13;
            return score1;
        }
        if((ranks[rank1[k]].compare(ranks[12])))
        {
            cout << userName << " got 14 points for having a Queen in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 14;
            return score1;
        }
    }

    cout << "" << endl;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if((ranks[rank2[i]].compare(ranks[0])))
        {
            cout << "The dealer got 2 points for having rank 2 in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 2;
            return score2;
        }
        if((ranks[rank2[i]].compare(ranks[1])))
        {
            cout << "The dealer got 3 points for having rank 3 in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 3;
            return score2;
        }
        if((ranks[rank2[i]].compare(ranks[2])))
        {
            cout << "The dealer got 4 points for having rank 4 in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 4;
            return score2;
        }
        if((ranks[rank2[i]].compare(ranks[3])))
        {
            cout << "The dealer got 5 points for having rank 5 in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 5;
            return score2;
        }
        if((ranks[rank2[i]].compare(ranks[4])))
        {
            cout << "The dealer got 6 points for having rank 6 in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 6;
            return score2;
        }
        if((ranks[rank2[i]].compare(ranks[5])))
        {
            cout << "The dealer got 7 points for having rank 7 in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 7;
            return score2;
        }
        if((ranks[rank2[i]].compare(ranks[6])))
        {
            cout << "The dealer got 8 points for having rank 8 in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 8;
            return score2;
        }
        if((ranks[rank2[i]].compare(ranks[7])))
        {
            cout << "The dealer got 9 points for having rank 9 in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 9;
            return score2;
        }
        if((ranks[rank2[i]].compare(ranks[8])))
        {
            cout << "The dealer got 10 points for having rank 10 in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 10;
            return score2;
        }
        if((ranks[rank2[i]].compare(ranks[9])))
        {
            cout << "The dealer got 11 points for having a Jack in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 11;
            return score2;
        }
        if((ranks[rank2[i]].compare(ranks[10])))
        {
            cout << "The dealer got 12 points for having an Ace in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 12;
            return score2;
        }
        if((ranks[rank2[i]].compare(ranks[11])))
        {
            cout << "The dealer got 13 points for having a King in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 13;
            return score2;
        }
        if((ranks[rank2[i]].compare(ranks[12])))
        {
            cout << "The dealer got 14 points for having a Queen in their cards!" << endl;
            score1 += 14;
            return score2;
        }
    }
}

//Associated Variables
string userName;
int deck[52];
string suits[4] = {"Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades"};
string ranks[13] = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Ace", "King", "Queen"};
int rank1[5];
int suit1[5];
int rank2[5];
int suit2[5];
int score1;
int score2;
```

I also tried if(ranks[rank1[i]] == "2") and if(rank1[i] == 2) but both had the same error as the method above where it would only execute the first if statement even when the condition has not been met.

Comment: Don't just try stuff randomly. `"2"`, `'2'` and `2` are *completely different things*. Do you understand the differences? Do you know how to compare in each case?

Comment: Its so amazyng what beginners can produce

Comment: Tip: `rand()` is trash, *especially* for games like this where predictability is a huge liability. Use [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

Comment: Well, it looks like you forgot what [`std::string::compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) returns (hint: it's not a boolean)

Comment: Tip: Most card games use a notation like `"2S"`, `"TD"` and `"AC"` to represent the two of spades, the ten of hearts and the ace of clubs respectively. This makes it very easy to handle the values as they're either `char[2]` or `char[3]` if you prefer them to also be valid C strings for convenience.

Comment: Tip: This near-endless chain of `if` statements with only tiny differences suggests you need to look at how to use loops effectively. Dry that up with `for`.

Comment: @JakubDóka Thank you for your very insightful reply. I only started C++ recently so sorry for not producing a AAA game but I need to start somewhere.

Comment: @tadman I will probably have to start this all over again judging by the comments here but I will take your tips into consideration. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I think you dug yourself into a bit of a hole here, but that happens to the best of us all the time. I'd suggest starting smaller, making simple functions that perform a specific activity, like that rank calculation, and testing those properly with a unit testing tool (example: [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2)). Once you're sure they're working correctly, start assembling those. There's nothing worse than trying to debug a bunch of code you've never run before and aren't even sure where something might have gone wrong.

Comment: You can also notice that your code has some repeating paterns in it, they can be solved by simple loop.

Comment: you need to use the compare() in following way  `if((ranks[rank1[k]].compare(ranks[0])) == 0) ` when strings are equal, btw you have array of strings so `if( ranks[rank1[k]] == ranks[0] )` is better way of writing it